# Inheritance in Python

Tags: python, inheritance

I'm having a small amount of difficulty understanding inheritance in Python. I was under the impression that when `Class B` inherits from `Class A` it inherits all of the values that were initialized in A. I've made up an example to demonstrate what I mean:

```
Class A():
    def __init__(self,parameter):
        self.initialize_parameter=4*parameter

Class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def function(self,another_parameter):
        return self.initialize_parameter*another_parameter
```

But in this case, calling:

```
B_instance=B()
print B_instance.function(10)
```

Returns an `AttributeError` saying that class B doesn't not have `self.initialized_parameter`

So my question is, do I have to copy and paste all the initializations from A to B manually or is there a way that I can use them from within B without calling the A class itself? (I hope this is clear).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to use the behaviour in the superclass' constructor you should either not override it:

```
Class B(A):
  def function(self,another_parameter):
    return self.initialize_parameter*another_parameter
```

Or if you want to extend the initialization behaviour you can use `super()`

```
Class B(A):
  def __init__(self, parameter)
    super(B, self).__init__(2*parameter)

  def function(self,another_parameter):
    return self.initialize_parameter*another_parameter
```

In Python 3 `super()` doesn't need explicit arguments (`super().__init__()`).

This general override behaviour and `super()` applies to all methods, not just constructors.

Comment: Nice answer nilem. Inheritance in Python in general is quite confusing, but you've summed it up nicely.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the `super` builtin in order to do the required initialisation for the parent class, like so:

```
class B(A):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

If you're not using Python 3, you might have to do it like this:

```
class B(A):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(A, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Basically this calls `A`'s `__init__` function which is required if you want to reference `A`'s methods and attributes.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to initialize the base class is to use `super().__init__()` in B `__init__()` method. See: [Understanding Python super() with __init__() methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576169/understanding-python-super-with-init-methods)

Answer (score 1):

You are overriding the constructor from the super class here:

```
def __init__(self):
    pass
```

So, `self.initialize_parameter` is never being initialized.

Delete that method, and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

The `__init__` of the superclass is only called automatically when you do not specify an `__init__` in the subclass. So you should not define `__init__` in class B unless you need to.
If you specify `__init__` in class B you have to call `__init__` in the superclass by hand. I prefer calling it this way: `A.__init__(self,'provide_initialize_parameter_here')`. Other people prefer using `super`.